# setting password for a user with adduser command

Tags: linux, user-accounts

Regarding the `useradd` command, there is an option `-p` for setting the password. But, it seems that it doesn't work and I have to later enter `passwd` command.

```
useradd -d /export/home/au -G users -p 123456 -s /bin/bash au
```

Also, there is a minor question. I want to redirect the default `/home/au` to `/export/home/au`. Should I use `-m` or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `-p` switch doesn't set the password directly, it sets an encrypted password as returned by the `crypt` function call. 
It is also disabled by default, as anyone listing the process (or who can later retrieve your bash history) can see the password you entered.

Regarding the `-m` switch, this only tells `useradd` to create the home directory if it doesn't already exist. Personally I've never used it, as CREATE_HOME is set to yes on all of my servers, and if the same is the case for you, then you won't need it.